# Trouble with object recognition in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am trying to call the `handleTap()` function as shown below and `let result: AnyObject` look for objects in another class that extends to `SCNScene`

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
 ...
  // add a tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
//(HANDLES A TAP BY THE USER)    NOT WORKING
func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("tap")
    //retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    //check what nodes are tapped
    let p = gestureRecognize.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: [:])
    //check that we clicked on at least one object
    if hitResults.count > 0
    {
        //retrieved the first clicked object
        let result: AnyObject = hitResults[0]

        //get its material
        let material = result.node!.geometry!.firstMaterial!

        //highlight it
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.2
    }
```

The function works however it is supposed to highlight a node which is located in another `class AppScene` that extends to `SCNScene`

```
    class AppScene: SCNScene
    {
     //objects are located in here
    }
```

I am trying to find a way to make the `handleTap()` function to search for objects that are children of `AppScene()` as it doesn't work right now.

Comment: It is hard to understand which part is «not working» (what the expected result is, compared to what it currently does). If you're talking about the animation, note that you're retrieving a material but don't do anything with it.

Comment: In my code I have it highlight the object as in the starter code of a scenekit project, and I didnt include it for the sake of making the code more focused on the problem. The part that is not working is that in the function handleTap() the objects are supposed to highlight but they aren't. I think it is because my objects that are supposed to be highlighted are in another class, but I am not sure.

Comment: So it seems that the gesture recogniser is not playing any role here. You should try to reduce your issue to its simplest form. For instance put your hit-testing code right in `viewDidLoad`. Then print `hitResults`. Does it contain anything? If not, print the node hierarchy. If you've got a result, apply the same logic at every step.

Comment: I dont think i can put the hit testing code in my `viewDidLoad` because it is called as a function. And the output of the code when i print `hitResults` is `[]` so yeah nothing in it

Comment: Im thinking about putting the objects I want to tap in my `GameViewController` and declare their properties inside that class so the gesture recognizer will understand I am tapping an object